# ruby hash not updating. trying to remove words from hash value

Tags: ruby, hash

```
REMOVE_WORDS_ARRAY = ["llc", "co", "corp", "inc", "the"]

businesses_array = import_csv.import('businesses.csv')
print businesses_array
# [["the bakery", "10012"]["law office inc", "10014"]]

businesses_hashes = []
our_hash = {}

businesses_array.each do |business|
  our_hash['BusinessName']  = business[0].strip unless business[0].nil?
  our_hash['BusinessZipCode'] = business[1].strip unless business[1].nil?

  our_hash.each {|key, value|
    our_hash[key] = value.downcase!
    our_hash[key] = (value.split(' ') - REMOVE_WORDS_ARRAY) # only this part doesn't get updated. why?
    our_hash[key] = value.gsub(' ', '+')
  }
  businesses_hashes << our_hash  
  our_hash = {}
end
```

when I print `our_hash` I can see that the name has been downcased and `+` have been added, but words haven't been removed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it ***does*** get updated, but then the value gets overwritten.

```
our_hash[key] = value.downcase! # destructive operation, value mutates in-place
our_hash[key] = (value.split(' ') - REMOVE_WORDS_ARRAY) # remove words and set to hash
our_hash[key] = value.gsub(' ', '+') # use downcased value from the first step, not from the second
```

Comment the third line out and you'll see. Also, second line returns an array. Did you forget to add `.join(' ')` at the end?

How to fix? Do it with one fluid motion :)

```
our_hash[key] = (value.downcase.split(' ') - REMOVE_WORDS_ARRAY).join('+')
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems are

- You are replacing a string with an array, and trying to do string operations on it.
- (As Sergio points out,) you are going back to the original `value`, so the previous operations become irrelevant.

There are several more problems. A better code would be

```
RemoveWordsRegex = Regexp.union(REMOVE_WORDS_ARRAY.map{|s| /\b#{s}\b/})

businesses_array.each do |name, zip|
  businesses_hashes <<
  {"BusinessName" => name.to_s, "BusinessZipCode" => zip.to_s}
  .values.each{|value|
    value.strip!
    value.downcase!
    value.gsub!(RemoveWordsRegex, "")
    value.gsub!(/\s+/, "+")
  }
end
```